# Intelligent robotic arm and its control system

Tags: control, robotic-arm, artificial-intelligence

As I know, most of robotic arms are specific-purpose and usually work under supervision of an expert, such as surgery robot. So, is this relevant for a robotic arm to be intelligent and autonomous? If so, how its control system may be different from non-intelligent ones?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to [Ask](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Eilia, but I'm afraid that questions like this are off-topic because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are only noticing the robotic systems that get a lot of press coverage.   Specialized, supervisory-controlled robotic systems are definitely *not* the most common.  Check out [this list of industrial robotic systems](https://roboticsandautomationnews.com/2015/07/21/top-8-industrial-robot-companies-and-how-many-robots-they-have-around-the-world/812/) for quantities of general-purpose, reprogrammable, robot systems for comparison purposes.   Whether or not reprogrammable industrial robots are *intelligent* is a matter of speculation and argumentation.   It depends on your definitions of autonomous and intelligent.

Answer (score 0):

At first it is important to distinguish between a Robot Control System itself and the development process to program such a system. A reasonable Control System is [NREC Operator Control System](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2rC_kmGuqU) which can control a robot arm. But a way more interesting is to program such systems. In most cases at the beginning is a teleoperating system, where a human-operator controls a robot with a Xbox-Controller. Than a parser is programmed for detecting actions. The next step converts the parser into a trajectory generator. Then, a time-scheduler follows and perhaps a sampling-based solver like [DARRT](http://lis.csail.mit.edu/pubs/barry-iser12.pdf).